# Ancient Serial Reader/GPS Error

Tags: java, netbeans, gps, serial-port

I am working on fixing the GPS functionality on some software that I have taken over from an old employee, and I keep having the following error thrown:

```
"org.dinopolis.gpstool.gpsinput.GPSException: port 'COM256' not available.
    at org.dinopolis.gpstool.gpsinput.GPSSerialDevice.open(GPSSerialDevice.java:135)
    at org.dinopolis.gpstool.gpsinput.nmea.GPSNmeaDataProcessor.open(GPSNmeaDataProcessor.java:146)"
```

I believe the gpsCounter may be the problem, but it doesn't seem to be reading the NMEA header data at all(cf. Code below). I'm at a loss. Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
public void activateGPS(String portName, boolean activate, int gpsCounter, GPSDialog gpsDialog) {
    //lets try loading GPS data and printing it to system.out

    if (!activate && gpsProcessor != null) {
        //the GPS was previously activated and we want to close it, or the user
        // is a moron and clicked OK without enabling the GPS
        try {
            gpsProcessor.close();
            GPSEnabled.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
            System.out.println("code Executed!");
            GPSEnabled.setText("Disabled");
            GPSActivated = false;
            return;
        } catch (GPSException e3) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Closing GPS", "SeaView Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            DefaultExceptionHandler handler = new DefaultExceptionHandler();
            handler.logException(e3);
        }
    }
    gpsProcessor = new GPSNmeaDataProcessor();
    try {
        //create GPS Device From Serial Port
        Hashtable<String, Object> environment = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        environment.put(GPSSerialDevice.PORT_NAME_KEY, portName);
        environment.put(GPSSerialDevice.PORT_SPEED_KEY, new Integer(4800));
        GPSDevice gpsDevice = new GPSSerialDevice();
        gpsDevice.init(environment);
        //TEMP
        //System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        //connect processor with device and open it
        gpsProcessor.setGPSDevice(gpsDevice);
        gpsProcessor.open();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GPS connected on port: " + portName, "SeaView Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        gpsDialog.disposeThis();
    } catch (GPSException e) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        //System.out.println("Calling again " + gpsCounter);
        gpsCounter++;

        //Call method recursivley until port 100 is reached.
        if (gpsCounter <= 256) {

            String comm = "COM" + gpsCounter;
            //System.out.println("comm " + comm);
            activateGPS(comm, true, gpsCounter, null);
        } else {

            gpsCounter = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error reading GPS.",
                    "SeaView Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            DefaultExceptionHandler handler = new DefaultExceptionHandler();
            handler.logException(e);
            try {

                gpsProcessor.close();
               // GPSActivated = false;
                return;
            } catch (GPSException e2) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Closing GPS", "SeaView Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                handler.logException(e2);
            }
        }
    }
    PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            Object value = event.getNewValue();
            String name = event.getPropertyName();
            //System.out.println("Name: " + name);

            if (name.equals(GPSDataProcessor.LOCATION)) {
                GPSPosition position = (GPSPosition) value;
                //System.out.println("The New Location is " + position.getLatitude() + "/" + position.getLongitude());
                gpsLat = position.getLatitude();
                gpsLong = position.getLongitude();
                mainFrame.updateGPS((float) gpsLat, (float) gpsLong);
            } else if (name.equals(GPSDataProcessor.NUMBER_SATELLITES)) {
                Integer number = (Integer) value;
                //System.out.println("Number of satellites: " + number);
            }

        }
    };

    try {
        gpsProcessor.addGPSDataChangeListener(listener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error adding change listener" + e);
    }
    GPSEnabled.setForeground(new Color(0, 150, 50));
    GPSEnabled.setText("Enabled");
    GPSActivated = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure COM256 actually exists?  I'm pretty sure that it only goes up to 255 on Windows.

Comment: It does not, gpsCounter is just a counter. It throws the same error no matter what the number in this  if (gpsCounter <= *) statement is. Even though it somehow assigns the port number, I am not able to see how it is being connected to the serial port or how it is reading it.